# Load testing an rpc application

Tags: c++, qt, rpc, thrift, grpc

I am working on an rpc application, I have used basic bench-marking methods to test the application like time taken for a ping-pong or time taken for sending specific bytes of data from client to server and back.
My question, Is there any other way or method to benchmark rpc applications?